# arduino + optotriac based ac dimmer blinking severely

Tags: arduino, dimmer

I try to build a dimmer with arduino phase control and triac.
I followed the schematic from[image: http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-controlled-light-dimmer-The-circuit]

http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-controlled-light-dimmer-The-circuit.

Now I used the software provided in the instructable link, but it is not working as it should.
The light is simply blinking instead of dimming.
So I used the following software to just glow the bulb without dimming:

```
unsigned int i=1;
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(AC_pin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
    attachInterrupt(0, light, RISING);
}

void light(){
    i++;
    digitalWrite(11, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
}

void loop(){
    if(i%100==0){
    Serial.println("100");
    i=1;
    }
}
```

Following are the results:
In the above code I am testing the zero crossing circuit just by counting upto 100, and printing a value (100) when it turns hundred. When i run the system without load (pin 11 is not connected to opto triac) it gives me almost perfect print rate of 1 per second (visibly) and steady. Now if i connect pin 11 to opto triac 3021, the output load bulb starts blinking (not steady at all), and also the output of optocoupler (4n25) gets randomized; Visibily i can see it is not giving output at every 1 second, rather it is somewhat random.
Please note instead of MOC3021 i am using EL3021, and in place of TIC206 triac i used bt 136. I am not using any snubber right now.
I also tried the software from http://wiki.dxarts.washington.edu/groups/general/wiki/4dd69/AC_Dimmer_Circuit.html. Still with no luck however their schematic is little bit different in terms of biasing but i am using exact values from the schematic attached.
Please help me sorting out this problem.

Thanks in advance.
Debojit

Comment: What sort of bulb do you use? Incandescent? LED? Halogen? Tube?

Comment: What happens if you change `light()` as follows: `{ digitalWrite(11, HIGH); delayMicroseconds(100); digitalWrite(11, LOW); }` ?

Comment: @jippie: I am using plain light bulb hopefully that is called incandescent. And i will try testing with 100 usec delay tonight my time.

Comment: @jippie: In the mean time please let me know i apply a steady high signal to the moc3021 input, would it not stay high. And one more thing: when i connect the arduino output to moc3021 why the 4n25 output timing issue is arising. Also i wanted to know what is the pulse width (time) of the zero cross signal. Should i use any snubber for the moc3021 along with a snubber for the load. Will keep u posted about the outcomes

Comment: If i remove the led and the 220 ohm resistor from  the optocoupler input would it help getting better output. I asked too many questions and i am sorry for that but i am desperate to solve the issue. Please bear me.

Comment: Don't remove the resistor, you'll kill the opto.

Comment: ultimately success.... removing the led did the job, thanks for your suggestion. Now i think the led is eating too much, and the rest is not sufficient to drive the opto. Should i use any gain with npn transistor, if i really want that led to turn on.