# Which transistor should I use in place of a 5V relay to adjust brightness of lights (230V) with the Arduino?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, transistors, relay, solid-state-relay

I want to control brightness of lights (230V) with the Arduino, and I know that relays will just switch the lights on/off. If you have the circuit or any idea about which transistor to use and how to use then please reply.

(Sorry for my English.)

Comment: The method (circuit) for dimming 230V lights depends on the type of lights. A transistor connected to an Arduino will not be enough and will likely be a lethal hazard.

Comment: I'll obviously not connect the transistor direct to the Arduino. Transistor will driven by circuit of other transistors.

Comment: What kind of lights? Incandescent, LED, CCFL? How powerfull it is, or you needed it to be?

Comment: I want to adjust brightness of CFL, Bulbs and also want to control the speed of ceiling fan.

Answer (score 2):

Although being quite simple, **this circuit is not for begginers. It is connected directly to mains!** If not properly designed, dangerous voltages can reach your Arduino and PC.

You will need an optocoupler for proper isolation. Also you will not be using a transistor, you'll need a triac.

Check this schematic from [wiki.dxarts.washington.edu](http://wiki.dxarts.washington.edu/groups/general/wiki/4dd69/AC_Dimmer_Circuit.html)

[image]

It is using [MOC3020M](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/MO/MOC3012M.pdf) which contains an optoisolator and triac driver.

Similar schematic can also be found on [Arduino Playground](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/ACPhaseControl).

**Do not build a circuit without proper isolation!**

**Do not replace MOC3020 with other parts (optocoupler and transistor/diac) unless you know what you are doing!**

Comment: You might want to edit this answer to say how well it works with a 230V Fluorescent light tube or with a 230V LED light. Incandescents are somewhat rare in the EU and maybe elsewhere too.

Comment: @TanishqJaiswal note that it doesn't work for CCFL.

Comment: Then can you give me a circuit diagram or link if I want to dim bulbs.

Comment: @TanishqJaiswal check this http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/68246/arduino-optotriac-based-ac-dimmer-blinking-severely